# Window with a view controller

Tags: ios

Hi guys i am trying to make a window with a view controller (which i guess is like GroupBox in .Net (fix me if i'm wrong..)) and i was trying to start the application on the simulator and it threw an exception. I am using storyboards.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    self.arSongsCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self.arSongsCollection;
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [_arSongsCollection addObject:[[Song alloc] initWithTitle:@"Song" andArtist:@"Artist" andURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://songurl.com/song.mp3"]]];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Read more about tableview datasources, here's the problem:

```
_tableView.dataSource = self.arSongsCollection;
```

this ususally should also point to self

```
_tableView.dataSource = self;
```

and you have to implement both necessary tableview delegate and dataSource methods in the view controller class.